# Need a Way to retrieve data from second table using C# Linq in Entity Framework Core

Tags: ef-code-first, ef-core-2.0

I'm unable to return the child data from the second table linked buy a Foreign key with the first table.

I have the following Tables that has been created using Entity Framework Core Code first approach :

```
 public class BoardGame
 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public List<BoardGameTitle> BoardGameTitle{get;set;}
 }

 public class BoardGameTitle
 {
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }

     public int languageId { get; set; }

     public int BoardGameId{get;set;}
     public BoardGame BoardGame{get;set;}
  }

 public class TableFlipDB :DbContext{
        public TableFlipDB (DbContextOptions<TableFlipDB> options)
        :base(options)
        {}

        public DbSet<BoardGame> BoardGame{get;set;}
        public DbSet<BoardGameTitle> BoardGameTitle{get;set;}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
            modelBuilder.Entity<BoardGame>().HasMany(bg=>bg.BoardGameTitle).WithOne(bg=>bg.BoardGame);
            //modelBuilder.Entity<BoardGameTitle>().HasOne(BoardGameTitle=>BoardGameTitle.BoardGame).WithMany(BoardGameTitle=>BoardGameTitle.BoardGameTitle);
        }
    }
```

the second table  `BoardGameTitle` contains a Foreign key to the following table `BoardGame` through the property `BoardGameId`,

When ever I retrieve the list of board games I cant get the related data from the second table in the property `BoardGameTitle` the property returns null

my Controller

```
 public ActionResult<List<BoardGame>> GetAll()
 {
   return TableFlipDB.BoardGame.ToList();
 }
```

Expected Result was:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "price": 100,
    "boardGameTitle": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "b1",
        "description": "b1",
        "languageId": 1,
        "boardGameId": 1,
        "boardGame": {
          "id": 1,
          "price": 100,
          "boardGameTitle": []
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "price": 200,
    "boardGameTitle": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "b2",
        "description": "b2",
        "languageId": 1,
        "boardGameId": 2,
        "boardGame": {
          "id": 2,
          "price": 200,
          "boardGameTitle": [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "b22",
              "description": "b22",
              "languageId": 2,
              "boardGameId": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "b22",
        "description": "b22",
        "languageId": 2,
        "boardGameId": 2,
        "boardGame": {
          "id": 2,
          "price": 200,
          "boardGameTitle": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "b2",
              "description": "b2",
              "languageId": 1,
              "boardGameId": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But the Result I got

`[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "price": 100,
    "boardGameTitle": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "price": 200,
    "boardGameTitle": null
  }
]`

Comment: change your select to `TableFlipDB.BoardGame.Include(p=>p.BoardGameTitle).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks @ElyasEsna that resolved my problem much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution as @Elyas Esna in the comments section said I need to change the controller return statement from `return TableFlipDB.BoardGame.ToList();` to `return TableFlipDB.BoardGame.Include(p=>p.BoardGameTitle).ToList();`